# A particular paragraph in Deep Learning - Bengio

Tags: probability, deep-learning

This question concerns with the  [chapter on RNNs](http://goodfeli.github.io/dlbook/contents/rnn.html#pf2) in the 
Deep learning look by Prof Bengio. 
In section 10.2.2 on page 336 in the last paragraph, the book talks about
"...because the outputs are the result of a softmax, it must be that the input sequence is a sequence of symbols...".

This seems to suggest that the output is treated as a probability distribution over the possible 'bits' and the next input x(t+1) is sampled using this joint probability distribution over the output bits. Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: isn't this more a mathematics question than a programming question?

Comment: It is, in some sense. Is there a more appropriate place this should be in? I'm sorry if this isn't the appropriate place for this question.

Comment: also see the update to my answer, completely forgot about that paper at first

Comment: Oh, I haven't come across this paper before. Sure, I'll go through it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the interpretation is not correct (unless my interpretation of your interpretation is incorrect). `x` is an input, and it is fixed in advance, so `x(t+1)` does not depend on the predicted value for timestep `t`.

In that paragraph he discusses a particular case of an RNN, where `y(t)` is a prediction of `x(t + 1)`, in other words, the network is trying to predict the next symbol given all the previous symbols.

My understanding of the sentence you are referring to is that since `y` is a result of a softmax, `y` has a limited range of values it can assume, and therefore `x` on itself has to be limited to the same range of values, hence `x` has to be a "symbol or bounded integer". Otherwise, if `x`, for instance, is a double, `y` cannot predict it, since the output of a softmax is a discrete value.

UPDATE: as a matter of fact, Bengio has a great paper:
http://arxiv.org/abs/1506.03099
in which he actually suggests that on some iterations we use `y(t)` instead of `x(t+1)` as input when predict `y(t+1)` during training (which is along the lines of your understanding in your question).